# Java method reference throws NPE

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

So I got a class

```
public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

    MenuBarController controller;

    public MenuBar() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(createMenuItem("Report", controller::writeReport));
        menu.add(createMenuItem("Save", controller::save));
        menu.add(createMenuItem("Import", controller::importFile));
        menu.add(createMenuItem("Clear DB", controller::clearDatabase));
        add(menu);
    }

    public void setController(MenuBarController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```

`MenuBarController` is an interface whose implementation is set via `setController` after the MenuBar ist created. The code throws a NullpointerException at `menu.add(createMenuItem("Report", controller::writeReport))` which can only be caused by `controller::writeReport`. If I replace this with a lambda like `() -> controller.writeReport()` no NPE is thrown.

**1. Why does `controller::writeReport` throw an NPE?**

**2. Why doesn't the lambda throw an NPE?**

The funny part is: If I replace the lambda with the method reference used before after I ran it once with the lambda, no more NPEs are thrown.

Anyone got any idea why that could be? Some javac / eclipse weirdness?

Comment: What is the call stack of NPE? What exactly is null?

Comment: this bug report looks relevant: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131323

Comment: `controller::writeReport throw an NPE?` because `controller` is null. You are trying to reference a method on a null object -> NPE.

Comment: Note that this runs without an NPE when compiled with Eclipse 4.4.1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`controller::writeReport` throws an NPE because `controller` is null when the line is evaluated.

`() -> controller.writeReport()` does not throw an NPE because by the time the lambda is run, `controller` has been given a value.

Comment: This is more obvious if you write the lambda as `() -> this.controller.writeReport()`, with an explicit receiver (which is what the lambda means anyway).  Then it becomes easier to see that the lambda is capturing `this`, not `controller`, which is why the two behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131323 explains why that happens. Method references work differently from lambdas, the method reference (not the method itself) is not evaluated lazily as it would be in a lambda.